# Is the Selenium click() recognized as human or automation?

Tags: selenium, automation, click, appium

My scenario which produces the question goes something like below:

I enter a webpage via normal means, next I press on a button, to start a HTML5 application on this webpage, this application is inside an iFrame. On application start I'm being prompted to either turn the sound on or off. At this point there are two possible outcomes:

`1. When I answer this prompt manually, new buttons appear in the application window, as expected.`

`2. When I answer this prompt through automation via Appium, new buttons do not appear.`

Now to the question:

> To answer the prompt I use the click() method from Selenium. Is it possible that this click() is not considered to be executed by a human and therefore doesn't trigger necessary things? And since I don't have access to the source of the application can I force the Selenium click() to look exactly like a human click?

Here is the code I use to execute the mentioned click:

```
//Application loading up, hence the sleep
Thread.sleep(5000);
AppiumTestBase.getDriver().switchTo().frame("e_iframe");
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement soundOff = AppiumTestBase.getDriver().findElement(By.id("soundOff"));
AppiumTestBase.getStandardWaitTime().until(elementToBeClickable(soundOff));
soundOff.click();
```

The program is able to find and switch in to the iFrame, there are no cross-origin issues either. The AppiumTestBase is just there for initializing the driver, setup capabilities etc. I also tried clicking the element via Actions and JavaScript, but there was no change in behavior.

Comment: I've never heard of / seen a `click()` work differently based on whether a human or `selenium` does it. Can you add some code to clarify how your click action is being executed? Are you switching focus to the new **iFrame** once the application starts?

Comment: @AJC24 Added some code, pretty standard.

Comment: One thing I'd ask is whether it's ever reaching that `click()` action. For example: is it getting any further than your **wait for element to be clickable** instruction? Just offhand, your code doesn't look quite right for that. It should read `AppiumTestBase.getStandardWaitTime().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(soundOff));`. You're missing using `ExpectedConditions` there.

Comment: @AJC24 Yes it reaches and executes the click(). The mentioned soundOff prompt disappears. Than the code starts looking for another element, which apparently doesn't get displayed, due to the problem I stated at the beginning. It's true that I'm missing the ExpectedConditions, but that isn't necessary for the code to work, I tried it just in case.

Comment: OK another thing to look out for - you're using `AppiumTestBase.getDriver()` twice in your code. Is the initialisation of `WebDriver` done once and the very same instance of that returned both times? Or is it creating a new instance each time? I'm guessing you're returning the same instance both times but just trying to rule out things one by one :)

Comment: @AJC24 Sure thing. Your guess is right, I only initialize the WebDriver once and getDriver() returns this instance.

Comment: I'm running out of suggestions for you at this point if I'm honest. You are maintaining a consistent `WebDriver` instance (ie. instantiate once only). You have switched to the correct **<iframe>** element, your code is finding the element, it is waiting for the element to be clickable (and does bypass it correctly) and the use of the `click()` method on the element is fine. Have to admit - I'm stumped!

Comment: @AJC24 No worries, so am I! :) But thanks for your input. If I somehow find a solution or a dirty workaround I'll post it here.

Comment: WebDriver will simulate actions just like user, but on browsing i think tap will work here. https://discuss.appium.io/t/difference-between-click-and-tap/295

Comment: @muraliselenium I tried a lot of things, and I think I already tried tap, but I'm not sure since it has been so much that I tried. But I'll try it out again as soon as I can and reply here, thank you.

Comment: @muraliselenium Ok I tried to perform a tap, but it does nothing. I read that tap shouldn't work in web view, maybe that's why. Since click() and tap() don't work I might also try to just execute the corresponding Javascript to trigger the listener with executeScript().

Answer (score 2):

In C# a workaround I've found to actually take control of the mouse and move it/click with it is to use "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting" for the Keyboard/Mouse libraries.  From there, you can tell it "Mouse.Click(new Point(X, Y));"and it will move your mouse to that location and click.

Sample Code:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;

var soundOff = AppiumTestBase.getDriver().findElement(By.id("soundOff"));
Mouse.Click(new Point(soundOff.Bounds.X, soundOff.Bounds.Y));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried this approach as well and, apparently, it didn't work either.

Comment: @CharlesNough I'm not too sure about an answer then, sorry about that.  The only other thing I'd be able to suggest is trying a different program like inputsimulator: https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

Comment: Don't worry, thanks anyway. I found a very dirty workaround, still have to look in to it, to see if it is really viable. The gist of it is that the application is expecting a special kind of touch event, which selenium/appium can not fulfil, atleast that's what I think.